# Can I put a function inside of a function?

Tags: c

Im currently taking a COP 3223 class and im learning about function atm. I was just wondering if its possible to put a function inside of a function.  Example:

```
void StudentId(int *);
int CourseLoad();
void invoiceCRN0();
//-------------------------------------------------------------
int main()
{
    int x,y;
    int load;
    StudentId(&x);
    CourseLoad();

    if (CourseLoad()==0)printf("Hello"); 
    return 0;
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------
void StudentId(int *id)
{
    printf("Enter your student id: ");
    scanf("%d", id);
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------
int CourseLoad()
{
    int crnload;
    printf("How many courses (up to 3)?: ");
    scanf("%d", crnload);
    if(crnload==0) return 0;
    if(crnload==1) return 1;
    if(crnload==2) return 2;
    if(crnload==3) return 3;

}
//-------------------------------------------------------------
void invoiceCRN0()
{
    int crm1;
    printf("Enter your class code: ");
    scanf("%d", crm1);
    switch (crm1)
    {
        case 1:
            printf("something");
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("something1");
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("something2");
            break;

    }
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Heres an example of a piece of code that will run a function inside of another function. Im basically trying to have it like this but instead of the main function printing out "Invalid CRN" if the return value is 0, I want it to print out an entire function like invoiceCRN0

```
#include <stdio.h> 
//hint for Project 4 
 
//---------------------------------------- 
 
int checkCrn ( int crn);// returns 1 if crn is OK, 0 otherwise 
int getCreditHours ( int crn ); // returns the credit hours of crn 
char* printPrefix ( int crn); //prints the prefix of crn 
 
//--------------------------- 
void  main( ) 
{ 
 
    int crn1, crn2, crn3; 
 
    printf ("Enter your three course numbers :"); 
    scanf ("%d%d%d", &crn1, &crn2, &crn3); 
 
    if(checkCrn(crn1)*checkCrn(crn2)*checkCrn(crn3) == 0) printf ("Invalid crn!\n"); 
    else { 
 
        printf ("%d\t%s\t%d\n", crn1, printPrefix (crn1), getCreditHours(crn1)); 
        printf ("%d\t%s\t%d\n", crn2, printPrefix (crn2), getCreditHours(crn2)); 
        printf ("%d\t%s\t%d\n", crn3, printPrefix (crn3), getCreditHours(crn3)); 
 
    } 
 
} 
 
//--------------------------- 
int checkCrn ( int crn) 
{ 
    if ( crn != 9696 && crn != 4587 && crn != 4599 ) return 0; 
    return 1; 
} 
//--------------------------- 
 
int getCreditHours ( int crn ) 
{ 
    switch ( crn ) 
    { 
        case 9696: return 5; 
        case 4587: return 3; 
        case 4599: return 1; 
    } 
 
} 
//--------------------------- 
char* printPrefix ( int crn ) 
{ 
    switch ( crn ) 
    { 
        case 9696: return "MAT 111"; 
        case 4587: return "COP 222"; 
        case 4599: return "STA 200"; 
    } 
 
}
```

Comment: The C standard does not define behavior for defining functions inside functions. Some C implementations provide it as an extension. But the code you show does not have any functions defined inside functions. Each of the functions shown, `main`, `StudentID`, `CourseLoad`, and `invoiceCRN0`, is defined separately. What do you mean by a function inside a function? Show a specific example of that.

Comment: Ill edit my post with an example of what I want. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: After update, none of those are nested functions; they're just functions calling functions (which is exactly what `main` was doing in the first case, in three separate places). The only real problems with the latter are (a) `void` as a return type for main, which is non-standard; it should be int. (b) both `getCreditHours` and `printPrefix` have code paths that can reach no-return-specified state. Ex: what happens when `printPrefix` is called with a value that is **not** 969, 4587, or 4599? What is returned? Clean all of that up and it should be ok.

Comment: @4386427 They're clearly confusing *defining* a function inside another function with *calling* a function inside another function.

Comment: Yes, in C,  like in any (sane) language, you can call functions from other functions. Otherwise the C language would be pretty useless.

Answer (score 2):

> I was just wondering if its possible to put a function inside of a function.

As far as I can tell from your code, you are asking about putting a function *call* inside a function.  Not only can you do so, but in C that is the **only** place where you can put function calls.

The opposite is true of function *definitions*: standard C does not provide for defining a function (by providing the function body) inside the body of another function.  All function definitions must be at file scope, outside of any other definition.